# Distinguish between app restart and activity change inside Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-lifecycle

I've got a ListFragment that needs to restore some stuff when the user opens the app. The "stuff" should be stored when the user closes the app. Both `store()` and `restore()` manipulate the ListFragment's ListView, so they need to be called somewhere where the ListView is created and available.

My current implementation uses `onPause()` to call `store()` and `onResume()` to call `restore()`. That seemed to work initially, but it has the side effect of storing and restoring also when the user enters and leaves the PreferenceActivity.

I'm not sure where in the ListFragment's lifecycle to make the calls to only have them fire on application shutdown and startup? Remember, the ListFragment's ListView needs to be accessible, so I guess onCreate() is out of the question? Some guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: you tried onStart() and onStop()?;

Comment: @ElDuderino Yes, but they fire when the user opens/closes the preferences as well, which is not what I want. I also tried `onActivityCreated()` and `onDestroyView()`, but neither of them seem to be able to access the ListView... Starting of thinking I need to set a flag somewhere to indicate app start/stop...